# How to test with Espresso one phone is call, the other one is answer?

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator, spoon

I am beginner to UI automation test with ** Espresso ** and I wonder that, if I wrote two test cases, one is making a call and the other one is answering a call. How can I run two different test cases to different simulator phones. I don't have an idea to logic and I don't found some documentations for this problem. I also used Spoon for running multiple devices. Please help me.